# Android Fragment Height

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have a fragment which placed into a **FrameLayout** on **MainActivity** programmatically. In the fragment, I needed a **GridView**. But it will have fixed 9 rows and 3 cols. There would be no scroll. So, I placed RecyclerView and created my own LayoutManager extending from GridLayoutManager.

```
@Override
public boolean canScrollVertically() {
    return false;
}
```

this part of the code provided blocking the scroll. 
I need a **Height** parameter of that FrameLayout and send it from Fragment to RecyclerView Adapter. Because, I planned to get size, and divide it into 9, then apply that new Height to each item.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_catalog_list, container, false);

        // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();

            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;

            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new NonScrollGridLayoutManager(context, columnCount));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new CatalogRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS, catalogListener, height - 200));
        }
        return view;
}
```

As you can see in the code, I got the height size from window metrics. **Not from the layout of the Fragment.**

And in the RecyclerViewAdapter, I calculate the height

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_catalog, parent, false);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = layoutHeight / 9;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

I am trying to get the Height value from the layout of the **Fragment**. But it always return 0. What should I do? I am looking forward to hear your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreateView()` is too early. You can attach a `ViewTreeObserver` to your Fragment's layout, and capture the value when it has a non-zero height and width value. I believe you can use a `ViewTreeObserver` for this:

```
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if(view.getHeight() > 0 && view.getWidth() > 0) {
                //cache values
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call

```
yourLayout.getHeight();
```

in `onCreate()`, `onStart()` or `onResume()`, it will return 0 in most case.

The better way to get the height of a layout in one of that method is this:

```
int height;

yourLayout.post( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            height = yourLayout.getHeight();
        }
    });
```

All Views have an Handler object, in this way you use the Handler of your Layout (that is a child of `View` class).